# install pcl-conversions when pcl is already installed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nowadays I installed PCL from source code because of a bug in pre-built binaries.

And now I want to install two packages ros-indigo-pcl-ros and ros-indigo-pcl-conversions using apt-get command.

But it says pcl-1.7 will be installed again.

I think installing pcl-1.7 again is redundant because I've already installed it from source code.

Is there any way to let `apt-get` know pcl-1.7 is already installed and skip installing it?

The resulting message of `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions` is as follow.

> The following extra packages will be
> installed:   libpcl-1.7-all
> libpcl-1.7-all-dev libpcl-1.7-bin
> libpcl-1.7-doc   libpcl-apps-1.7
> libpcl-apps-1.7-dev libpcl-common-1.7
> libpcl-common-1.7-dev
> libpcl-features-1.7
> libpcl-features-1.7-dev
> libpcl-filters-1.7
> libpcl-filters-1.7-dev
> libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev libpcl-io-1.7
> libpcl-io-1.7-dev libpcl-kdtree-1.7
> libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev
> libpcl-keypoints-1.7
> libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev
> libpcl-octree-1.7
> libpcl-octree-1.7-dev
> libpcl-outofcore-1.7
> libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev
> libpcl-people-1.7
> libpcl-people-1.7-dev
> libpcl-recognition-1.7
> libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev
> libpcl-registration-1.7
> libpcl-registration-1.7-dev
> libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7
> libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev
> libpcl-search-1.7
> libpcl-search-1.7-dev
> libpcl-segmentation-1.7
> libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev
> libpcl-surface-1.7
> libpcl-surface-1.7-dev
> libpcl-tracking-1.7
> libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev
> libpcl-visualization-1.7
> libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev The
> following NEW packages will be
> installed:   libpcl-1.7-all
> libpcl-1.7-all-dev libpcl-1.7-bin
> libpcl-1.7-doc   libpcl-apps-1.7
> libpcl-apps-1.7-dev libpcl-common-1.7
> libpcl-common-1.7-dev
> libpcl-features-1.7
> libpcl-features-1.7-dev
> libpcl-filters-1.7
> libpcl-filters-1.7-dev
> libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev libpcl-io-1.7
> libpcl-io-1.7-dev libpcl-kdtree-1.7
> libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev
> libpcl-keypoints-1.7
> libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev
> libpcl-octree-1.7
> libpcl-octree-1.7-dev
> libpcl-outofcore-1.7
> libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev
> libpcl-people-1.7
> libpcl-people-1.7-dev
> libpcl-recognition-1.7
> libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev
> libpcl-registration-1.7
> libpcl-registration-1.7-dev
> libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7
> libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev
> libpcl-search-1.7
> libpcl-search-1.7-dev
> libpcl-segmentation-1.7
> libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev
> libpcl-surface-1.7
> libpcl-surface-1.7-dev
> libpcl-tracking-1.7
> libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev
> libpcl-visualization-1.7
> libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev
> ros-indigo-pcl-conversions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232714/install-pcl-conversions-when-pcl-is-already-installed/) by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version of pcl_conversions that you can install through apt was compiled against the version of pcl that you can install through apt.

If you want to use pcl_conversions with a version of pcl that you've built from source, you should also build pcl_conversions from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1